Convert Boost v1.80 RegEx to Excel VBA RegEx
According to the Notepad++ User Manual Notepad++ uses the Boost Regular Expression library v1.80, and I have some expressions that I would like to put into some VBA code using Excel 2013.
While there is a dedicated library to do this I have no idea how Boost's RegEx might differ from VBA's, or how to convert one to the other.
While the RegExs used in VBA code look identical to what I've been doing, I'm going to be using both search and replace functionality, and replacement syntax is often different between programs.  (Such as whether a matched group is referenced with $n or \n.)
Does anyone know a regular expression for converting Notepad++ RegExs to VBA? Or perhaps someone can confirm that the syntax between the two programs is truly 100% identical? (I haven't tried anything in VBA yet.)

VBA itself has no regular expressions. When talking about RegEx in VBA, usually it is ment to use the VBScript 5.5 library. You can use it in your VBA project by adding a reference to the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" library (or use late binding if you insist).
The probably best information about the details of that library you can find on the website of Jan Goyvaerts. Have a look to regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html. I will not repeat the whole content of that side, just this:

Basically, Internet Explorer 5.5 implements the JavaScript regular expression flavor. But IE 5.5 did not score very high on web standards. There are quite a few differences between its implementation of JavaScript regular expressions and the actual standard. Fortunately, most are corner cases that are not likely to affect you.

Best bet is to try your existing regexes - there are enough examples here and elsewhere how to use the library with VBA
Update Anyone interested in RegEx usage in VBA should have a look to How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops

VBA RegEx doesn't work the same way.  When I try to replace text it treats \n \L and other \ characters as literals.
